# Toggling problem of D flip flop

Tags: frequency, flipflop

how to do frequency divider by 2 without having the toggling issue ? Since I just want to divide the frequency by half and align that signal with single pulse signal.

Comment: What's "the toggling issue"?

Answer (score 2):

Dividing a signal to half the frequency does involve toggling unfortunately. It appears that your consternation is that you started with a narrow pulse signal and do not want to end up with something like this:

[image]

I suspect that what you were thinking of instead was a resulting waveform that looked more like this:

[image]

There are a number of ways to achieve this type of result but I'll show one that uses commonly available logic gates.

[image]

In the above circuit use logic parts from the same logic family such that the path delay of the input signal through the two upper AND gates is slightly longer than the path delay through the flip flop from the CLK rising edge to the Q output. If the flip flop that you choose to use has an inverted Q output you can remove the inverter shown and simply feed back the inverted Q back to the D input.

An alternative design that would be more suitable for implementation in a programmable logic device such as a CPLD or FPGA could follow the design shown below.

[image]

Comment: Where did you get the secret decoder ring to translate that question? Bravo! +1 for an excellent answer, +1000 for figuring out what the question was.

Comment: Ugh. -100 for using gate delays to avoid glitches. It would be far better to toggle the FF on the falling edge of the input pulses. Either use a negative-edge triggered FF, or put an inverter in the path to its clock input.